# Try Except handling with a function in Python

Tags: python

I'm not very well versed in exception handling, and was wondering what happens in a case where the try successfully calls a function, but then there is an error within said function.

```
try:
    foo()
except:
    ...

def foo():
    ...    # error happens here (no exception handling)
```

Is the error handled or will we get an error in this case.

Comment: For above case, error will be caught from try and the system will run the content inside except

Comment: I googled "python exception tutorial" and the very first result covers this (and more!) :) https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/

Comment: I have added an answer hope it will help you

Comment: Design a little test script (by generating an exception in `foo` and putting a print statement in the except clause)! You'll go farther faster if you don't rely on others to hand you answers that you can discover for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error would be caught by the try outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

It will fall through to your try-except clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to catch your error, whenever the specific error occurred the except block code will run:

```
try:
    foo()
except ErrorName:
   # handle ErrorName exception
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify what's going on:

This program fails due to the function being called before defined:

```
try:
    foo()
except:
    print("failed")
def foo():
    print("my string")
```

The error is caught in the try, thus printing "failed"

Defining the function prior makes the program work:

```
def foo():
    print("my string")
try:
    foo()
except:
    print("failed")
```